# Assigning using += gives NaN in javascript

Tags: javascript, nan, compound-assignment

Assignment a number to an attribute using the `+=` operator gives me `NaN` in JavaScript.

This code works as expected:

```
> var result = {};
undefined
> result['value'] = 10;
10
> result['value'] += 10;
20
```

But here we get `NaN`:

```
> var test = {};
undefined
> test['value'] += 10;
NaN
```

Why does JavaScript behave like this? How can I get this to work without initializing `result['value'] = 0`?

Comment: What is wrong with initialising it?

Comment: well what would you expect the result to be when summing up "undefined" and a number ? Doesn't seem so strange...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't add a number to `undefined` in JavaScript. If you don't want to initialize the number, you need to [test if it's `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property) before incrementing it:

```
test['value'] = (typeof test['value']==='undefined') ? 10 : test['value']+10;
```

Answer (score 11):

This line `test['value'] += 10` equals to `test['value'] = undefined + 10`, which is `NaN` (Not a Number).

Comment: You haven't told OP how to fix his problem, though.

Comment: @Blazemonger I just want to give him the fishing rod. It will be more interesting.

Comment: A good idea, but that should be done with comments. When you submit an answer, you should actually be "answering" the entire question.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you're trying to add `10` to an `undefined` property of your object, so your line will result in doing:

```
test['value'] = undefined + 10; // NaN
```

**Every numerical expression which causes an unknown value turns into `NaN` (not a number) in JavaScript**. To make it work, you should check if that property exists and has a numerical value, then add some number to it; otherwise you'll have to create it. Plus, since that you're working with an object, you can use `test.value` instead of `test['value']`.

Here is an example:

```
if (Number(test.value)) test.value += 10;
else test.value = 10;

// Or more neatly:
test.value = +test.value ? test.value + 10 : 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `test['value']` is `undefined`. Adding a number to `undefined` will give you `NaN` (which stand for "Not a Number"). You need to initialize the value before adding to it:

```
var test = {};
test['value'] = 0;
test['value'] += 10;
```

Since you are using an object you can also use the dot notation:

```
var test = {};
test.value = 0;
test.value += 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test['value'] += 10;
```

is equivalent to
`test['value']  = test['value'] + 10;`
but, `test['value']` is undefined, because you haven't initialized it yet

Answer (score 1):

> Why does JavaScript behave like this?

Because when the property does not exist, accessing it defaults to `undefined`; and when adding a number to `undefined` you get `NaN` back.

> How can I get this to work without initializing `result['value'] = 0`?

If you don't want to (or can't) initialize it once, you will need to check every time whether the property exists, basically:

```
test.value = ('value' in test ? test.value : 0) + 10;
```

Another approach would be to cast the property to a number every time before adding to it:

```
test.value |= 0;
test.value += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if test value is not undefined before adding the value:

```
test['value']? test['value']+=10 : test['value']=10
```

Comment: Technically, this only tests if its value is "falsey".

Comment: Ecmascript5 definition of the conditional operator: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12

`LogicalORExpression ? AssignmentExpression : AssignmentExpression`

then the

`AssignmentExpression` is defined here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13

Answer (score 0):

Because NaN can't be added. You need to have a number to use +=

Comment: can you give a bit of more explanation?